# Write dpi metadata to a jpeg image in Java

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, dpi, javax.imageio

I am trying to programatically set the dpi metadata of an jpeg image in Java. The source of the image is a scanner, so I get the horizontal/vertical resolution from TWAIN, along with the image raw data. I'd like to save this info for better print results.

Here's the code I have so far. It saves the raw image (byteArray) to a JPEG file, but it ignores the X/Ydensity information I specify via IIOMetadata. Any advice what I'm doing wrong?

Any other solution (third-party library, etc) would be welcome too.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream    

import org.w3c.dom.Element;    
import com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter;

public boolean saveJpeg(int[] byteArray, int width, int height, int dpi, String file)
{
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    WritableRaster wr = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    wr.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, byteArray);

    try
    {           
        // Image writer 
        JPEGImageWriter imageWriter = (JPEGImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(file));
        imageWriter.setOutput(ios);

        // Compression
        JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = (JPEGImageWriteParam) imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        jpegParams.setCompressionMode(JPEGImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(0.85f);

        // Metadata (dpi)
        IIOMetadata data = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(bufferedImage), jpegParams);
        Element tree = (Element)data.getAsTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0");
        Element jfif = (Element)tree.getElementsByTagName("app0JFIF").item(0);
        jfif.setAttribute("Xdensity", Integer.toString(dpi));
        jfif.setAttribute("Ydensity", Integer.toString(dpi));
        jfif.setAttribute("resUnits", "1"); // density is dots per inch         

        // Write and clean up
        imageWriter.write(data, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), jpegParams);
        ios.close();
        imageWriter.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some issues that were not considered here:

1. The tree is not directly mapped to the IOMetaData. To apply data from tree, add following call after setting the densities and raster parameters:

   ```
   data.setFromTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0", tree);
   ```
2. don't use the meta data as first parameter in the write call. See `JPEGImageWriter#write(IIOMetaData, IIOImage, ImageWriteParam)`. If streamMetaData is not NULL, a warning (WARNING_STREAM_METADATA_IGNORED) will be generated.
3. set the meta data as `IOMetadata` of the `IOImage`. These meta data are used by JPEGImageWriter. The correct write call then is

   ```
   imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(F_scaledImg, null, data), jpegParams);
   ```

Comment: Where is F_scaledImg set? Is it the same as bufferedImage?  Sorry if this is a dumb question...

Comment: Yes, it is in fact bufferedImage. Christoph must have copy-pasted the snippet and forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I would seem this could be a bug.

I found this post [from a few google searches](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t360709-imageio-iiometadatasetfromtree-cripples-data.html)

Apparently there are alot more that point to a bug as well.

The post above talks about using JMagick as a third party work around.